# Non-clickable links in Facebook timeline - what the what?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Since Sunday, whenever posting an external link on my client's Facebook page, the link shows up in standard form except the title of the link is in black and non clickable. Instead, to open the link one needs to click on the image which I suspect not many now nor are used to. The links were posted through dlvr.it and Buffer at different dates and times. The posts in question are:

https://www.facebook.com/azureholidays/posts/10152089073543589?stream_ref=10
https://www.facebook.com/azureholidays/posts/10152083370688589?stream_ref=10

Comment: Both are clickable for me.